# Using a SELECT query to get data from two different tables in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am really struggling to understand what is wrong with my query. When I use var_dump($sqli); it just echos out the entire query without any data in it.

I want to create a query so when a user searches for a city the returned search result would be the attractions associated with that city. I realise that there is a few errors with my code, however if I get the query completed I will go from there and debug the rest of the code. If anyone has any ideas as to why my query isn't working I would greatly appreciate them.

```
require_once('config1.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq = $_POST['search'];

$sqli = 'SELECT attraction_name, lat, long, cost FROM zz_attractions WHERE city_id IN SELECT city_id FROM zz_city WHERE city_name LIKE %searchq%' or die("could not search");
var_dump($sqli);

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 0) { 
    $output = 'there was no search results';
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqli)) { 
    $attraction_name = $row['attractionname'];
    $lat = $row['latitude'];
    $long = $row['longitude'];
    $cost = $row['cost'];

    $output .= '<div>'.$attraction_name.' '.$lat.' '.$long.' '.$cost.'</div>';

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are executing `var_dump` on a string.. use `var_dump` on `$result`

Comment: @Ice76 this returned bool(false). I am guessing it is false because there is an error in the query. Does anyone know what that is

Comment: try [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqli+find+error+in+query)?

Comment: Cut down your code until it compilies & runs tests then add stuff back. Echo your exact SQL strings. Read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query fails because you need the parentheses shown here:

```
  SELECT attraction_name, lat, long, cost 
  FROM zz_attractions 
  WHERE city_id IN (SELECT city_id 
                    FROM zz_city 
                    WHERE city_name 
                    LIKE '%searchq%')
```

But a better way to do it would be an inner join:

```
  SELECT a.attraction_name, a.lat, a.long, a.cost 
  FROM zz_attractions a
  INNER JOIN zz_city c ON a.city_id = c.city_id
  WHERE c.city_name LIKE '%searchq%'
```

### ----

just an observation, nothing more...

Never quite understood why PHP coders tend to have every SQL query as a single row

```
$query = '
  SELECT a.attraction_name, a.lat, a.long, a.cost 
  FROM zz_attractions a
  INNER JOIN zz_city c ON a.city_id = c.city_id
  WHERE c.city_name LIKE %searchq%
';

echo $query;
```

Comment: Ok thank you, so do I just replace my query with that? So it will read $sqli = and then the above code with a ; at the end?

Comment: I have given you valid SQL, you need to convert that into PHP

Comment: We recognize that OP is going to put a dollar sign in there, and dynamically generate the SQL text, blissfully unaware of [Little BobbyTables](https://xkcd.com/327/) style  [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) vulnerability. And its apparent that OP code isn't checking whether query execution was successful (and hasn't enabled mysqli connection to throw exceptions). OP will continue to be puzzled as to what is happening when MySQL throws an error.

Comment: @spencer7593 you might recognize that but not a PHP coder myself, just doing my bit to help on the sql side of it. Why do PHP coders use a vast long line for sql queries I wonder?

Comment: @Used_By_Already: I don't understand it either. Maybe its the pattern they learned when they first wrote "SELECT * FROM foo", no need for a line break there. Maybe they are unaware that line breaks in SQL text are *whitespace*. And it hasn't occurred to them that *formatting* SQL text will help a future reader, or maybe they aren't aware that some developers don't have displays that are 2000 characters wide. Or maybe they are writing code in notepad and have word wrap enabled, and figure everyone else does it that way. Who can tell?